# Facebook JS SDK - email response undefined

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i have a problem with facebook js sdk response;

i trying to make login with facebook. i use facebook js sdk.

this my code :

[Please go here](http://pastebin.com/ycy4hQEW)

and i get response just "id" and "name".
anyone can help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the fields you wish in return. But you query against API 2.0 i would suggest to update to v2.5!

Here you go:

```
v2.5/me?fields=name,link,id,email
```

Answer (score 1):

I already found the answer, seems that I forget to write the query string following '/me':

```
FB.api('/me?fields=name,email', function(response)
```

and

```
{scope: "public_profile email"}
```